# Watch state of an Object

Tags: dart, riverpod

I previously was watching state of some strings and booleans separately like the following:

```
var strSearchProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) {
  return "";
});

String strSearch  = ref.watch(strSearchProvider ); // this works
```

This time I tried to make a simple object including strings and booleans :

```
class AppState {
  String strSerach = "";
  bool playing = false;
  bool searching = false;
  AppState();
}

var appStateProvider = StateProvider<AppState>((ref) {
  return AppState();
});
```

Now I'm watching it like this:

```
// inside consumer buid method
 AppState watchedState = ref.watch(appStateProvider);

// some codes ..
appbar: AppBar(
          actions: !watchedState.searching
              ? [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                        onPressed: () {
                          ref.read(appStateProvider.notifier).update((state) {
                            state.searching = true;
                            return state;
                          });
                        }),
                  )
                ]
              : [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                        onPressed: () {
                          ref.read(appStateProvider.notifier).update((state) {
                            state.searching = false;
                            return state;
                          });
                        }),
                  )
                ],
 //the rest
```

But nothing happens when I press the search icon and watched state is not really watched.

So what should I do? is It a good practice to provide/watch everything separately ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point is that your state objects **should be immutable**. When you consider the simple types `int`, `String`, `bool`, `double` - everything will work as expected. But once you create an object, for example a collection or your own class, then at that moment you should take care of their mutability.

To make your class **immutable**, all of its fields must be marked `final`. Additionally, you need to take care of overriding `hashCode` and `==`. Changing an instance of such an object when there are many fields can be extremely inconvenient. It is for these purposes that the `freezed` or `equitable` packages were created, which do a lot of the work for us, including the useful `copyWith` method for quickly creating a new instance based on the old one.

As for collections such as `List`, `Map` and `Set` - they are **mutable** *by nature*. So whenever you need to change your state, which is a collection, you have to create a new instance of the collection. For a list, for example, simple ways to do this are to use spread (`state = [...oldState];`) or use the `List.of` method.

Try to stick to these aspects and your code will be *reactive* :)